# How to stop/end drawing in Turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Could someone tell how to stop the drawing of this figure in Python?

Modify this code so it stops drawing after a certain number of iterations:

```
import turtle
g = 134
l = 120
while True:
    turtle.speed('fastest')
    turtle.left(g)
    turtle.forward(l)
```

Count of iterations should be with `input()` when starting the program.

Answer (score 3):

Well your problem is that you have your turtle drawing in an infinite loop, you are never really stopping your program from running.
when you say:

```
while True:
    turtle.speed('fastest')
    turtle.left(g)
    turtle.forward(l)
```

This is your infinite loop and without any set condition for this to stop it never will.Now to answer how you would be able to do this with a set number of iterations. You can do this one of two ways in `while` or a `for` loop. Most of the time if you want to run a certain block of code a set amount of times a `for` loop is your best bet.

```
import turtle
g = 134
l = 120
num_iter = input()
for i in range(num_iter):
    turtle.speed('fastest')
    turtle.left(g)
    turtle.forward(l)
```

Here `for i in range(num_iter)` this declares a for loop that runs num_iter amount of times. Hopefully this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will run forever, since you have created an infinite `while` loop. To solve this, you can use a `for` loop. The number of iterations can be put in the `range()`

```
import turtle
turtle = turtle.Turtle()
g = 134
l = 120
iterations = int(input("..."))
for _ in range(iterations):
    turtle.speed('fastest')
    turtle.left(g)
    turtle.forward(l)
```

This way, the code will stop running after the specified iterations.